# how to create a custom container with three individual buttons inside

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a custom widget that is a rounded rectangle containing 3 iconButtons, used for navigation. but, as far as I have seen, iconButtons cannot be used outside of material widgets, and i don't know how to wrap them in a widget that doesn't mess up my UI.

1. just a container with iconButtons throws "no material widget found, iconButton widgets require material widget"
2. trying to wrap with a material widget, i get positional arguments, messing up my UI
3. i have tried wrapping my container in other widgets to no avail.

here is a piece of my code, just one of the icons in the container. the code repeats twice with different icon and onPressed before closing the widget.
i really would like my UI to look how i planned, and for these buttons to work.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 50.0,
      width: 200.0,
     // color: Colors.grey[800],
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[800],
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all( Radius.circular(50.0)),
        ),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('test');
                          },
                        ) // IconButton
                      ], // <Widget>[]
                  ) //Column
                ), // Container
```

Comment: Show the screenshot of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Where are you using this widget? As long as one of its parents is a scaffold, there shouldn't be a problem - but if you are navigating to a new context and then building this widget, you would need to include a new scaffold. A Dialog works too I believe.

Comment: the widget is a custom widget i made in its own file, and then called to it in my main UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code in `Scaffold` and it will work.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Container(
      height: 50.0,
      width: 200.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[800],
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('test');
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ); // IconButton ], // [] ) //Column ), // Container
}
```

Comment: That worked! Before, I was getting positional argument errors when i tried to implement anything like that, not sure what the issue was. Thanks!

Comment: If that helped, can you mark this answer as accepted. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGwTL.png) how to accept answer